# F string is adding new line

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I am trying to make a name generator. I am using F string to concatenate the first and the last names. But instead of getting them together, I am getting them in a new line.

```
print(f"Random Name Generated is:\n{random.choice(firstname_list)}{random.choice(surname_list)}")
```

This give the output as:

```
    Random Name Generated is:
Yung 
heady
```

Instead of:

```
Random Name Generated is:

Yung heady
```

[image]

Can someone please explain why so?

Comment: Are there newlines at the end of each name?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi there MUST be newllines at the end of the names

Comment: @Programmer Well, guess why I am asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had pulled these values from UTF-8 encoded .txt file, the readlines() did convert the names to list elements but they had a hidden '\xa0\n' in it.

This caused this particular printing problem. Using .strip() helped to remove the spaces.

```
print(f"Random Name Generated is:\n{random.choice(firstname_list).strip()} {random.choice(surname_list).strip()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems right, perhaps could be of newlines (\n) characters in element of list.
Check the strings of lists.

```
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
      firstname_list = ["yung1", "yung2", "yung3"]
      surname_list = ["heady1", "heady2", "heady3"]
      firstname_list = [name.replace('\n', '') for name in firstname_list] 
      print(f"Random Name Generated is:\n{random.choice(firstname_list)} {random.choice(surname_list)}")
```

Output:

```
Random Name Generated is:
yung3 heady2
```

Comment: Indeed there were. As I had pulled the values from a UTF-8 encoded .txt file, there were newlines within the elements of the list themselves. I used .strip() to resolve this problem.

print(f"Random Name Generated is:\n{random.choice(firstname_list).strip()} {random.choice(surname_list).strip()}")